# Center align textboxes in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

What i want to do is to center align the 3 textboxes and button. How can i do this?

```
 <div class="navbar_foot navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">


        <form class="navbar-form navbar-middle">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row featurette">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="inputLarge"
                            value="" placeholder="Email Address">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="email"
                            value="" placeholder="Repeat Email Address">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="lName"
                            value="" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register
                            Today</button>
                        <a href="#myModal" role="button" id="myButt"
                            class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch
                            Demo Modal</a>

                    </div>


                </div>



            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar_foot .navbar-collapse_foot {
    text-align: center;
    align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? Do you have some sort of example like a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: i have also added the CSS script to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is working if you remove `.navbar-collapse_foot`:

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/6BEmY/

```
.navbar_foot{
    text-align: center;
    align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want them beside, not underneath, each other:

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/Mhy7P/

Comment: That's the same i code i have. But it doesn't work. And i want the text boxes and button to be sideways not underneath one another

Comment: Remove .navbar-collapse_foot - see the fiddle.

Comment: @Illep check my edited answer for how to have them on the same line.

Comment: Yes, it works. But the text boxes have become smaller (the width is smaller). Is there a way to increase the width of the text-boxes and button?

Comment: You can change <div class="col-md-3"> under div class="row featurette"> to <div class="col-md-9"> for example or as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add these lines to your css file:

```
.col-md-3 {
text-align: center
}
```

This will make your text boxes aligned in the center.

Tested in: http://jsbin.com/kekan/1/edit

Comment: i want the text boxes and button to be sideways not underneath one another

Comment: @Illep

instead of using divs you can try using span.

Try this now: http://jsbin.com/kekan/2/edit